# Need to compare two collections and then either add or remove the DBAName

Tags: c#, performance, linq, lambda, logic

In entity framework and Web API2 I have a PUT that receives a LegalEntity model legalEnt. The LegalEntity model has a collection of DBANames. I need to compare all of the DBAName objects that legalEnt provides against the DBANames collection called dba that I get from the database where LegalEntityID matches.

If the DBANames collection that come from the UI as LegalEnt are missing a DBAName in comparison with the collection in the database then I need to remove that missing DBAName from the database. Also if there is an extra DBAName from the UI then I need to add that DBAName.

I am not so concerned with my syntax as I am with the logic of identifying the missing or extra DBAName and then removing it. To me this is a logic exercise. I am thinking that I need to loop through each collection and then put objects in an array to be added or removed (addArray and delArray). But how to do this is not immediately obvious to me.

```
public IHttpActionResult Put(LegalEntity legalEnt)
{        
        List<DBAName> dba = new List<DBAName>();
        dba = db.DBAName.Where(d => d.LegalEntityID == legalEnt.LegalEntityID).ToList();

        foreach(var legal in legalEnt.DBANames)
        {
            foreach(var d in dba)
            {
                do something
            }
            maybe do something else
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep your code short and simple, you can use Linq as follows:

```
public IHttpActionResult Put(LegalEntity legalEnt)
{        
    List<DBAName> dba = new List<DBAName>();
    dba = db.DBAName.Where(d => d.LegalEntityID == legalEnt.LegalEntityID).ToList();

    var addArray = legalEnt.DBANames.Where(x => !dba.Select(y => y.LegalEntityID).Contains(x.LegalEntityID)).ToArray();
    var delArray = dba.Where(x => !legalEnt.DBANames.Select(y => y.LegalEntityID).Contains(x.LegalEntityID)).ToArray();
}
```

---

Another approach is this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Put(LegalEntity legalEnt)
{        
    List<DBAName> dba = new List<DBAName>();
    dba = db.DBAName.Where(d => d.LegalEntityID == legalEnt.LegalEntityID).ToList();

    var addArray = legalEnt.DBANames.Select(x => x.LegalEntityID).Except(dba.Select(y => y.LegalEntityID)).ToList();
    var delArray = dba.Select(x => x.LegalEntityID).Except(legalEnt.DBANames.Select(y => y.LegalEntityID)).ToList();
}
```

In this way you will get a list of int.

---

The last approach  would be to use the `Except` method between the two lists. Basically your `DBAName` class should implement `IEquatable<DBAName>` to let the framework know how to compare the entities.

If you are interested, please see more documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx).

---

Anyway after all, I would chose the first method :)

Comment: I used your arrays but just changed the addArray to .Contains(x.Names)).ToArray(); as Names is the description string and I changed the delArray to .Contains(x.DBANameID)*).ToArray();